# Should the off topic close text be changed?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions

The text which appears after closing a question reads:

> **closed** as off topic by User1, User2, Mod♦ Date at time
>
> Questions on Electrical Engineering - Stack Exchange are expected to generally relate to electronics, within the scope defined in the [faq](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq).

The FAQ, I think, is good, but this text is bad.  When closing a consumer electronics question, the "generally relate to electronics" clause doesn't make sense.

Could we change this to "generally relate to electronics design"?

Comment: Sounds like a great idea to me.

Comment: Site title and artwork should also be changed to "electronics design".

Comment: @rwong - We can't do that, unfortunately, because of a trademark dispute.  See this question: [ANNOUNCEMENT - Site Title Change](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/565/announcement-site-title-change)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated the description and it will show up after our next deploy.